# integral of Trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, integration

$\begin{align}
(1)\quad &\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+1}}\mathrm dx\\
(2)\quad &\int\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm dx
\end{align}$

How can I solve these types of integrals?

Comment: http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=How%20to%20integrate%20sinx%2Fx&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=387be0b8a88fce2b&ion=1&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=387be0b8a88fce2b&biw=1043&bih=589&ion=1

Comment: @DJC I doubt that this is homework. Would take an evil teacher to assign these "problems" :-) (But of course, point taken: the OP should've put more effort in framing the question.)

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word here.  "Evaluate" is appropriate.

Comment: @Srivatsan: I agree, and that's a fair point, though I suppose that might depend on the level of the class.  Nonetheless, the question is not well motivated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno already mentioned that both of the OP's integrands are not expressible in terms of "usual" functions; I'll address the "how can I evaluate" portion of the question for the first integral.

Letting $x=\tan\frac{u}{2}$, $\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm du}{1+\cos\,u}$ (the Weierstrass substitution), we get

$$\int \frac1{(1+\cos\,u)\sqrt{1+\tan^4\frac{u}{2}}}\mathrm du$$

$$\int \frac1{\sqrt{(1+\cos\,u)^2\left(1+\left(\frac{1-\cos\,u}{1+\cos\,u}\right)^2\right)}}\mathrm du$$

which simplifies to

$$\int\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{4-2\,\sin^2 u}}$$

Removing a factor of $\frac12$ from the integrand gives

$$\frac12\int\frac{\mathrm du}{\sqrt{1-\frac12\sin^2 u}}$$

which is easily recognized as the [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2.E4):

$$\frac12 F\left(u\mid\frac12\right)$$

Undoing the initial Weierstrass substitution yield the final result,

$$\frac12 F\left(2\arctan\,x\mid\frac12\right)$$

Alternatively, one could have instead used $x=\cot\frac{u}{2}$ as the substitution, but I'll leave that as an exercise...

Answer (score 7):

These integrals are not "elementary". The first one is basically an [elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind), which can be explicitly written in terms of hypergeometric functions after some manipulations (see [Euler's integral representation of hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type)).

The second one is the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html), which also has no representation in terms of elementary functions.

Hope this helps!